# Counting Cards Code Explanation

Tags: javascript

I am doing the FreeCodeCamp courses and am confused as to why my code doesn't work. It seems to be a messier version of the correct answer.  Below is the correct answer and underneath that is mine.  I just want to understand.

Here is the correct answer:

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  {
   case 2:
   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
  return count++;
   case 7:
   case 8:
   case 9:
  return count;
   case 10:
   case 'J':
   case 'Q':
   case 'K':
   case 'A':
  return count--;
 }
}
```

Here is my answer:

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  switch (card) {
    case 2:
      return count + 1;
    case 3:
      return count + 1;
    case 4:    
      return count + 1;
    case 5:
      return count + 1;
    case 6:
      return count + 1;
    case 7:
      return count + 0;
    case 8:
      return count + 0;
    case 9:
      return count + 0;
    case 10:
      return count - 1;
    case 'J':
      return count - 1;
    case 'Q':
      return count - 1;
    case 'K':
      return count - 1;
    case 'A':
      return count - 1;
  }
  if (count <= 0){
    return count + " hold";
  } else {
    return count + " bet";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two differences; what you get back and what is modified

- [`count++`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()) and [`count--`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--)) give you back the value of `count`, then modify `count`
- `count + 1` and `count - 1` give you back a calculated value based on count and do not modify count

Consider

```
let x = 1;
x++; // 1
x; // 2
```

vs

```
let x = 1;
x + 1; // 2
x; // 1
```

---

It is also worth noting that the unary  increment and decrement operators can be used prefix, which performs the modification before you get back the value, i.e.

```
let x = 1;
++x; // 2
x; // 2
```

---

Furthermore, please notice that it is impossible to reach your condition `if (count <= 0) ...` assuming `card` in `[2-9JQKA]|10` as an earlier `return` will always have been called.

---

Finally, as I can't see the input I can not be sure on this, however it looks like this code is mixing *Number* and *String*. It may be wise to consider choosing just one type so you do not get unexpected behaviour.

Depending on the behaviour you require for `A`, I would suggest either using *Number* and mapping `{J: 11, Q: 12, K: 13, A: 14}`, or doing everything in *String*.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  switch(card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count += 1;
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      count += 0;
      break;
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count -= 1;
      break;
  }

  return count + (count > 0 ? " Bet" : " Hold");
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.